# Power supply capability of the circuit

Tags: power-supply

I do not want to include a dedicated power supply for the operation of a low current demanding microcontroller chip in one of my projects. Instead I wish to use something which would just work fine. I couldn't think anything simpler than this circuit.

[image]

Though it may seem a very silly circuit and may fail at higher current requirement, but I guess it can power a microcontroller and a few LEDs(2 or 3) which will require just few milliAmps of current. Also, I can prevent the resetting of the IC due to minute voltage irregularities by adding some ceramic cap near the it.

This is what I can see as of now. Is this feasible to make and use such a circuit for practical purposes. What could go wrong?

Comment: Just use a USB supply... It will end up being the same size and not deadly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, it is possible to make this circuit work. And I actually saw a similar design used on an old wall-rechargeable flash light.

As for your question "What could go wrong", my answer is:

1 - Personal safety concern, as stated in the comments, is a major one. There is serious risk of electrocution.

2 - In case of any cap failing short, the rest of the capacitors will have to split that cap voltage, bringing them closer to their max rated voltage, thus making the whole circuit even more likely to fail.

3 - Linear regulator (IC7805 in your circuit) will need biasing current which reduces the current budget of the power supply.

I refrain from proposing solutions just in order to stay within the limits of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The current coming from the bridge rectifier will charge all the capacitors equally (until the total voltage is *about* 282 volts. But the microcontroller only discharges capacitor number 1. An equilibrium will be reached when capacitor 1 is empty, and capacitors 2-10 have *about* 282 volts in total. Then your microcontroller won't work any more because it has no power.

Answer (score 0):

**What could go wrong?**

The biggest problem is that this circuit is not isolated from the AC mains. This means that if you were to touch part of the circuit you could get an electrical shock. If you happened to be in the wrong situation *(which is more common than you would think)* the electrical shock can cause a few milliamperes of current to flow through your body and stop your heart. Result - you die.

The second problem, after your gone, someone investigates your device and suffers a like result.

The third problem is that using direct AC attached circuitry in an experimental manner can lead to sparks and fire when something accidental happens. That could be when a test lead comes loose and flops into the wrong place, you connect a meter incorrectly or even getting distracted by something like your child or cell phone.

Comment: Ok got it. You emphasize safety right! What if I do experiment correctly and enclose the circuit in a well isolated box?

Comment: @Bhuvnesh - Why would you even think to need that capability when the world is already more than full of millions of used and surplus cell phone chargers that output 5V. I propose that that solution costs way less than what your well isolated box with its AC inlet connector, power cord and primary rated capacitors would be. I can go to the local surplus outlet in my town and get used/recycled phone chargers for less than you would think.

Comment: Ok i understand! Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

A lot of power supply circuits for similar purpouses are made with capacitor in series on the AC side. On the DC side you get something like a constant current source that can be stabilized w/ parallel stabilizer.

A capacitive divider on the AC side is also an option and will be more like your picture.

Then again, looking at how you are asking, you are better off (and way safer!) with something factory-made.

p.s. where is this 200v mains? If it is Japan, you are playing with something in the kilowatts range, adding a fire to the electric hazard. Please, improve your competence first.

Answer (score 0):

That you are building is called "transformless power supply". They were popular in the past, when switching power supplies were still complex and expensive so the only alternative used to be the large 50 Hz transformers. They were both lighter and cheaper. You can read more about them [here](https://electrosome.com/transformerless-low-cost-power-supply/). The capacitors should be placed before the bridge rectifier, not after. And you need one more bigger electrolytic capacitor across the output of the rectifier to convert pulsating current into smooth and also some kind of voltage stabilizer.

These supplies do have advantages but they are quite dangerous devices that must be properly wired, grounded and isolated, with many things that can go wrong. I would strongly advice against using this design for exposed circuitry in amateur experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the notes on the circuit I've added and consider: -

[image]